# React Native hot reloading is not show in iPhone expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

I used expo.
if i modified my code, the app is not reload.
and it didn't reload if forced to reload button.
help me.
my phone is iphone. and my project expo init..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tjxv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shake your phone and the hot reloading button will appear.

Comment: this image is shake my phone.  and I pressed reload button but is not apply the change my code. and hot reloading button is not show.. please help me.

Comment: Hot reloading is being replaced with fast refresh

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10991 and also hot reloading not working with functional components and I don't know it has been fixed to not.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall and re-install expo-client on your phone. Solved